# Public vulnerability feed with CVSS v3

Tags: cve, nist, cvss

NIST NVD publishes XML feeds of CVEs but, as far as I'm concerned, only with CVSS v2 vectors. CVSS v3 results are available on web portal.

Is there available any up to date, processing friendly, raw data of CVEs with CVSS v3 base metrics? (preferably enriched with CWEs and temporal metrics)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NIST follows trends and recently has added [new (beta) JSON feeds with CVSSv3](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/data-feeds#JSON_FEED)

Comment: Does this mean that the NVD XML v2.0 feeds only contain the CVSS v2 score? 

I did not found any description or specification of that, can you provide a link which confirms this?